# Browserify doesn't work, "nativeMax is not a function"

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, firefox-addon, browserify

I'm coding browser extension which takes screenshot of website. I'm trying to use Pageres as it's written down here:

-index.js

```
const Pageres = require('pageres');

var pageres = new Pageres({delay: 2})
    .src(window.location.href, ['1920x1080'])
    .src('data:text/html,<h1>Awesome!</h1>', ['1024x768'])
    .dest('screenshots')
    .run();
```

As I know, require() can't be used in browser, so I needed to use Browserify and bundle it up. Bundling went well, but script doesn't work, it throws error:

```js
start = nativeMax(start === undefined ? (func.length - 1) : (+start || 0), 0);

TypeError: nativeMax is not a function
```

I tried Webpack and also bundled files successfully. But it also was throwing similar kind of error. Tried using import, didn't work too. Pageres module works perfectly, i tried it out separately. But I just can't implement it to the extension. How to make require() work with browserify and fix this error? Or maybe it is Pageres fault?

This error shows on Webpack version of extension:

```
TypeError: The "original" argument must be of type Function
```

I found out througe console.log debugging that with Webpack it stops right before 
    const Pageres = require('pageres');
but with Browserify console.log which is putted before this line doesn't shows.

Comment: Perhaps nativeMax is a stub for the browser's native max() function?  So the nativeMax() function would have some code that determines the browser you're using then use the max() function that is native to that browser.

Comment: @MarkMcWhirter the code which uses nativeMax is not mine, it's Lodash's from node_modules, should I modify it? The first declaration of it is this: nativeMax = Math.max;  The only code I wrote is this with pageres, made background.js too to call pageres on extension icon click, and that's all. I think it's Pageres which uses some of the modules.